# React Custom Hook - Typescript for return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a custom hook, for example:

```
type DataItem {
    id: number
    title: string
}

const useDataItem = (uid: string) => {
    const {data, setData} = useState<DateItem>()
    const {loading, setLoading} = useState<boolean>(false)
    const {error, setError} = useState<number>()
    
   // ...do stuff

   return {data, loading, error}
}
```

In a test, I mock this hook using the following:

```
const mockDataItem = {
    loading: false,
    error: undefined,
    data: { id: 1, title: 'test' }
}
jest.mock("../../hooks/useDataItem", () =>
  jest.fn(() => mockUseDataItem)
);
```

I'm looking for a way to get the type of the hook's result, so I can apply it to  `mockDataItem` (and not have to redeclare the type).

Is this possible, and if so then how?

Answer (score 3):

`typeof useDataItem` gives you the type of the function, and `ReturnType<FunctionType>` gives you the type of the function type's return value ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)), so: `ReturnType<typeof useDataItem>`

```typescript
const mockDataItem: ReturnType<typeof useDataItem> = {
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    loading: false,
    error: undefined,
    data: { id: 1, title: "test" },
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAERTo4DGMVA3AFCswCeYBAInjgCS+SgF5ErOFLjAAJgC44AO2QgARuihtpcGMBgAbdItQwowJQHM2hNq3oQlplBn65h6MXAAUyOSbMLSwBKOFEAPgkdByd4AG04WQEAGjgMGDccOABdMJcsXHwAHkyPSgAfFCVZdBILdFlw72DtaRjnBIMIHFkg1PSAGW7eqxy8tAK8dCK1CAgjHCUmkhwDDBbJNscOuE1yKH70GABRKH2x8QnsKaKVdU04SuRq2vrG5rsdAHovuAA6AGyCBpGDIEgkdg6WigqBKRCJFJwLo9Pq7M7QIg2OzteAgCD0ADWpREigASkdkLCACrcaZcHgQEj5YmeSLiBCbKTIkaWRQrNboZKctH7RTPGp1JQNIU6JK4RRIfxwACMqT0hmM1HwpioRCFtlYACt0KY-njCd4qACvtaABZzAmoL4TFkgKipZphSLG00kJTeT0RODmokCMrBFpAA) (with various typos and issues with `undefined` from the question fixed)

Answer (score 1):

add a return type to the hook

```
export interface DataItemType {
   // properties
}

const useDataItem = (uid: string):DataItemType => {
....

const mockDataItem = {
    loading: false,
    error: undefined,
    data: DataItemType
}
```